# I'd like to run an independent php page connecting to the mysql database on our WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, centos-web-panel

I've tried to output some info from the db but I get the following error :

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Then I tried it with a simple php page with nothing but echo "test"; and that created the same error.

I'm guessing this might have something to do with the htaccess created by WordPress but I'm not sure how to allow this page.

I tried an HTML page and that was allowed.

We are using CWP6 and I see that the file is owned by root instead of the user... not sure how I can change this.

EDITED TO ADD WORDPRESS HTACCESS :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: post the contents of your htaccess file

Comment: have a look on the webserver log and/or php error log

Comment: Hey guys... thanks for the comments and I'm going to post the relevant error log bits here.

Comment: The htaccess file is HUGE full of spam protection - iTheme and Hackrepair - plus the following wordpress stuff : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>